# -Compute the average for a 2D matrix in a loop

Tags: r, matrix, average

I made a script for reading 15 data files, computing a difference between each 2 files and writing the results to 5 different files. These 5 files are matrixes, 10x259 values. 
I need to make a matrix in which each element will be the average of the elements on the same position in the previous 5 matrixes. I can’t make the average work.

I tried the classic way of “sum=sum+i” inside the loop, but R gives an error for the recursive sum.
I tried making a 3 dimensional matrix and filling it with 5 “pages” containing 2D matrixes, but I get errors for trying to fill the matrix with a content of another size. 
I tried with rowMeans(), but can’t get it to do the job as I need to get the mean of 5 iterations of the same variable.

The only way I could do it is reading all the resulting files again into separate variables, adding them and dividing by 5. But this only works for a few files. I will need to extend to many files so I need to make it work in a loop somehow.

Can anyone give me a better idea?

I’m new to R. The script is probably very inefficient, but it only needs to do the job.

Below is my code:

```
MAM <- c("M","N","O","P","R")
S <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
T<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
V<-c("a","b","c","d","e")

Min2000<- array(3,dim=c(259,10,5))
Min2010<- array(5,dim=c(259,10,5))

  # this will be done 5 times
for (i in 1:5)  { 

  # preparing file names to be read
  S[i] <- paste(MAM [i],"2000.txt",sep="_")
  T[i] <- paste(MAM [i],"2150.txt",sep="_")
  V[i] <- paste(MAM [i],"2250.txt",sep="_")

  # import data from the files
  file1 <- read.table(S[i], header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  file2 <- read.table(T[i], header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  file3 <- read.table(V[i], header=TRUE,sep="\t")

  # delete the first column
  file1[,2:11]
  file2[,2:11]
  file3[,2:11]
  file1a <- file1[,c(2:11)]
  file2a <- file2[,c(2:11)]
  file3a <- file3[,c(2:11)]

  # compute data
  Min2000<- (file2a-file1a)/file1a
  Min2010<- (file3a-file1a)/file1a

  colMeans(Min2000)
  #cub[,,i]= Min2000    #doesn'twork
  #rowMeans(datamonth, dims = 2)  #doesn'twork
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see comment in code for explanation

```
# load library
library(dplyr)

# Create vectors of names to be read in
MAM <- c("M","N","O","P","R")
S.Name <- paste(MAM,"2000.txt",sep="_")
T.Name <- paste(MAM,"2150.txt",sep="_")
V.Name <- paste(MAM,"2250.txt",sep="_")

# Read in data into list and drop first column
S = lapply(S.Name, read.table, header = T, sep = "\t") %>% lapply(function(x) x[,-1])
T = lapply(T.Name, read.table, header = T, sep = "\t") %>% lapply(function(x) x[,-1])
V = lapply(V.Name, read.table, header = T, sep = "\t") %>% lapply(function(x) x[,-1])

# Sum up the files, then divide to find mean.
# This does (matrix1 + matrix2 + matrix3 + matrix4 + matrix5) / # of matrices
S = S %>% {Reduce("+", .) / length(S)}
T = T %>% {Reduce("+", .) / length(T)}
V = V %>% {Reduce("+", .) / length(V)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

```
Min2000<- array(NA,dim=c(259,10,5))
Min2010<- array(NA,dim=c(259,10,5))

# this will be done 5 times
for (i in 1:5)  { 

  # import data from the files
  file1 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)
  file2 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)
  file3 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)

  # delete the first column
  file1a <- file1[,-1]
  file2a <- file2[,-1]
  file3a <- file3[,-1]

  # compute data
  Min2000[,,i] <- (file2a-file1a)/file1a
  Min2010[,,i] <- (file3a-file1a)/file1a
}

A2 <- apply(Min2000,1:2,"mean")
A3 <- apply(Min2010,1:2,"mean")
```

.

```
Sum2 <- matrix(0,259,10)
Sum3 <- matrix(0,259,10)

# this will be done 5 times
for (i in 1:5)  { 

  # import data from the files
  file1 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)
  file2 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)
  file3 <- matrix(sample(1:10,2849,replace=TRUE),259,11)

  # delete the first column
  file1a <- file1[,-1]
  file2a <- file2[,-1]
  file3a <- file3[,-1]

  # compute data
  Sum2 <- Sum2 + (file2a-file1a)/file1a
  Sum3 <- Sum3 + (file3a-file1a)/file1a
}

B2 <- Sum2/5
B3 <- Sum3/5
```

I replaced the files by random matrices.

The result is *almost* the same:

```
> max((A2-B2)^2)
[1] 7.888609e-31

> max((A3-B3)^2)
[1] 7.888609e-31
```

Comment: I assume that the matrices have indeed 10 rows and 259 columns, not vice versa.

Comment: I changed the solution such that "file1", "file2" and "file3" are 259x11-matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers.

mra68, I tried both solutions. The first one (with: A2 <- apply(Min2000,1:2,"mean”and A3 <- apply(Min2010,1:2,"mean") gives me an error.
The second solution works perfectly (with: B2 <- Sum2/5, B3 <- Sum3/5). I obtained the mean that I needed.

Vlo, I tried the library but with your code I can make only the sum between the 10 columns and the mean of these columns. I wanted the mean between the 5 excels, not between the 10 columns. The code does more than I managed to do myself in the beginning, but it’s not exactly what I needed.